# X11: run a gnome app as another user

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x11, gnome, sudo

I have ubuntu + x11 + gnome.

I want to run a graphical application as another user.

However, when I start it from the command line using `sudo -u otheruser app` I get the error "No protocol specified".

How can I work arround this?

Comment: will be moved to superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
xdg-su -u user -c command
```

Comment: I believe you still need to use xhost to allow local connections from any user.

Comment: man xdg-su:  xdg-su is for use inside a desktop session only.

Answer (score 13):

`xhost '+si:localuser:USERNAME'`

Answer (score 8):

Execute this command first:

```
$ sudo xhost +
```

Then run the command you want as the other user:

```
$ sudo -i -u username
$ command you want to run
```

When you are done:

```
$ sudo xhost -
```

Comment: Nice find. Now Chrome and Flash runs fine as different user, but to get audio you need to pkill the pulseaudio-daemon of the current user first.

Comment: `sudo xhost +local:` if you don't want connections from the internet

Comment: `xhost +` is **highly unsafe**: It will allow any user to connect to your X session and open windows to you.

Comment: xhost +username to add username to list of users with access to the X server.
Then xhost -username to remove that user afterwards

Answer (score 2):

Most solutions provided here don't integrate with Wayland and PulseAudio.

I wrote `ego` (Alter Ego) for this use case, it automatically handles `xhost` and Wayland and PulseAudio socket sharing: https://github.com/intgr/ego

So you just run `ego app` or `ego -u somebody app`

If you run into problems, please open an issue on GitHub. I may be the only user of it, so it hasn't gotten much testing yet.

(And I notice that I'm a decade late with this answer, but hopefully it will help somebody :D)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to tell your X server to accept connections from another user than the one owning the server instance (you). Look into the xhost command.

Answer (score 0):

gksudo -u command

Comment: Tried this on my Ubuntu desktop, it did not work (same error msg. as in question).

Answer (score 0):

```
gksu -u <user> -c <command>
```

Replace `<user>` with the username to run the command as, and `<command`> with the command you want to run. Remember that the program will be run in the `<user>`s context, but in the current directory.

In the popping up window, enter the password of the target `<user>` of course.