# How can I fix this error from importing module pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I run the python code from the root. Shows an error when I just imported the module:

```
 ERROR : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/amir/photo.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pyautogui as gui
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/pyautogui/__init__.py", line 249, in <module>
    import mouseinfo
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/mouseinfo/__init__.py", line 223, in <module>
    _display = Display(os.environ['DISPLAY'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.display = _BaseDisplay(display)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/Xlib/display.py", line 62, in __init__
    display.Display.__init__(*(self, ) + args, **keys)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/Xlib/protocol/display.py", line 129, in __init__
    raise error.DisplayConnectionError(self.display_name, r.reason)
Xlib.error.DisplayConnectionError: Can't connect to display ":1": b'No protocol specified\n'
```

Comment: Maybe something from here helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1124171/x11-run-a-gnome-app-as-another-user

Comment: This is a security limitation X.  Your session is associated with your login user, and no other user can access it.  You might look here.  https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Running_GUI_applications_as_root